# Move footer to center of site on chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, design

The footer on chat is left aligned.  Can we **center** it so that we follow the format of all the other stack exchange sites?

> [image]

Is there any response by the team?  Perhaps @balpha?

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk -- Thanks.  I feel infinitely better about this feature request now.

Comment: +1 standard form should be followed on all sites.